# GVIM 7.3 exits with error information on Ubuntu 11.10 AMD64

Tags: gvim

I installed GVIM 7.3 from Ubuntu Software Center. I can successfully run it in a terminal but after it exits, warning messages will show in that terminal. I've tried to solve it but, no effect.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to get rid of these errors?

Thanks!

```
(gvim:1963): Gdk-WARNING **: Using Cairo rendering requires the drawable argument to
have a specified colormap. All windows have a colormap,
however, pixmaps only have colormap by default if they
were created with a non-NULL window argument. Otherwise
a colormap must be set on them with gdk_drawable_set_colormap

(gvim:1963): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cairo_region: assertion `region != NULL' failed

(gvim:1963): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cairo_region: assertion `region != NULL' failed

(gvim:1963): Gdk-WARNING **: Using Cairo rendering requires the drawable argument to
have a specified colormap. All windows have a colormap,
however, pixmaps only have colormap by default if they
were created with a non-NULL window argument. Otherwise
a colormap must be set on them with gdk_drawable_set_colormap

(gvim:1963): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cairo_region: assertion `region != NULL' failed

(gvim:1963): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cairo_region: assertion `region != NULL' failed
```

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).